# How to add a scrollbar that orientes its position on the top most widget

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I have a tkinter app in which I have a main canvas with multiple pages (all of which are frames). I pull up the different pages by rasing them with the frame.tkraise() command. I now want to add a scrollbar to the whole thing. The scrollbar appears but without a slider and I am not sure if it cna recognize the change of page.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Economics(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.columnconfigure(self, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Tk.rowconfigure(self, 0, weight=1)

        self.container = tk.Canvas()
        self.container.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.container.columnconfigure("all", weight=1)
        self.container.rowconfigure("all", weight=1)

        self.vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(orient="vertical", command=self.container.yview)

        self.container.configure(yscrollcomman=self.vscrollbar.set)

        self.vscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, ExamplePage1, ExamplePage2):                                                             # TUPLE OF PAGES

            frame = F(self.container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        self.container.delete("all")
        frame = self.frames[cont]

        self.container.create_window(0, 0, anchor="nw", window=frame)


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)

        button_1 = ttk.Button(self, text="Example Page 1",
                              command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ExamplePage1))
        button_1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        button_2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Example Page 2",
                              command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ExamplePage2))
        button_2.grid(row=1, column=0)


class ExamplePage1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)

        for i in range(50):
            label = tk.Label(self, text="Button {} of 50".format(i+1))
            label.grid(row=i, column=0)

        button_back = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                              command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button_back.grid(row=0, column=1)


class ExamplePage2(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        super().__init__(parent)

        for i in range(35):
            label = tk.Label(self, text="Button {} of 35".format(i+1))
            label.grid(row=i, column=0)

        button_back = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                                 command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button_back.grid(row=0, column=1)

app = Economics()
app.geometry("800x600")
app.resizable(True, True)
app.mainloop()
```

In this example file you can see the basic structure of my app with some example widgets and buttons. The scrollbar shows but without the slider. What do I have to change to get a working scrollbar for all pages.
Later on I'm planning to get a horizontal scrollbar as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't scroll items added to a canvas with `pack`, `place`, or `grid`. A canvas can only scroll items added via the canvas `create_*` functions, such as `create_window`.

Comment: I've edited the code so the pages appear inside a window, can you help me now? I'm sorry if I'm still missing simple stuff like before.